# I want to increase maxdepth to 128 for cosmosjsondotnetserlializer in cosmos db trigger function

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I get exception has been thrown by the change feed processor delegate. The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded.

I am only looking for workaround to increase maxdepth 128
We cannot change payload structure.

Tried many things but nothing is helpful

Example document to reproduce

```
{"id": "foo", "a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":{"a":1}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fairly recent change in response to [this issue](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr) (which states that nesting levels of ~20K can cause StackOverFlow exceptions and high levels in general use more CPU/RAM). Unfortunately no new property was added to [`CosmosSerializationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosserializationoptions?view=azure-dotnet) to easily override the 64 selection if inadequate.

As a POC I was able to get around this issue by changing my `Startup.cs` to the below

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDBSerializerFactory, MyCosmosDBSerializerFactory>();
    }

    public class MyCosmosDBSerializerFactory : ICosmosDBSerializerFactory
    {
        public CosmosSerializer CreateSerializer()
        {
            return new CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer(new CosmosSerializationOptions{ IgnoreNullValues = false});
        }
    }
}
```

And temporarily "borrowing" the code from the [`CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Serializer/CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer.cs) class in the SDK and changing `MaxDepth = 64` to `128`.

That code is "Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation." however so I wouldn't want to just go ahead and use it in a project - but at least it shows one way of implementing the expected interface with `Newtonsoft.Json` that you can have a look at and learn from.

I'm not sure if you need to actually supply any implementation of `ToStream` at all for the use case of deserializing change feed documents or can just use.

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

I didn't see it being called but my testing was extremely superficial.

TBH it is probably quite unwelcome news that you even have to think about this when all you want to do is get your documents available in the function so maybe you should create a feedback request asking for this to be exposed via `CosmosSerializationOptions`.

Comment: Do I need to make changes only in startup.cs and nothing in my function code?

Comment: Yes - I didn't need to change anything in my function. The "reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded" error was happening before the function itself was even called

Comment: After adding above i get the exception at function execution. Function execution failed because json reader has reached maxdepth 64 though i have set it to 128 can you help me paste the entire piece if code I need to update in startup class, just want to make sure I am not missing out anything

Comment: Did you use the **exact** code I posted? Including the `new CosmosSerializationOptions{ IgnoreNullValues = false}`? If you don't pass anything for that parameter then the `CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer` code linked above never gets to the bit setting the max depth because of the `if (cosmosSerializerOptions == null)  { this.SerializerSettings = null;   return; }`

Comment: So in your own implementation you would likely want to do something different

Comment: But it definitely worked for me so just put some break points in and see what is happening

Comment: Yeah I copied exactly as you pasted and then added entire internal sealed class cosmosjsondotnetserlializer : cosmoserializer from the link

Comment: "Function execution failed because json reader has reached maxdepth 64" is different from "exception has been thrown by the change feed processor delegate. The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded" - is this being caused by something inside the body of the function itself?

Comment: One other thing that might be relevant is that I had my function definition returning a collection of `JObject` - I wasn't mapping it to any strongly typed class. In case this is where the error has now moved to

Comment: Exception while executing function : xyz the reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded. This is the exact error .. initially it was exception thrown by Change feed processor delegate

Comment: I add the piece of code you gave above and then copy enitre code from the github link with only changing MaxDepth value to 128? It is correct or do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: That was the only change I needed to make to get past the error "exception has been thrown by the change feed processor delegate. The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded." and get the function called successfully - so you'll need to debug it and see what the call stack is for the new error

Comment: I think it gets past the error "exception has been thrown by the change feed processor delegate and tries to execute the function and then throws the error system.private.corelib: exception while executing function: xyz. Newtow.json: the reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded , I degraded Newtown.json to version 12 but still this error

Comment: I presume your function body is looping through a collection of documents. If you put a break point at the first line inside the loop is it getting that far?

Comment: Yes it is getting till the first line inside the loop, var doc= item.getpropertyvalue<dynamic>("document");

Comment: If you are calling `GetPropertyValue` then you must have a collection of `Document` - so I assume you are using the old SDK as this is internal in the new one. I was testing against the 4.x version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB

Comment: Using the above SDK this is how I have it configured and I don't see any issues reading properties from it in my limited testing https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSm41.png

Comment: I am using latest sdk  Microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.cosmosdb (4.3.0)

Comment: IReadOnlylist<Document> input, Ilogger log)                               {if (input != null && input.Count >0{ foreach (Document item in input{     
  var doc = item.Getpropertyvalue<dynamic>("xyz");

Comment: You shouldn't even be able to access the `Document` class in 4.x of the function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-cosmos-db-version-3-version-4?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#modify-your-function-code "The Azure Functions extension version 4 is built on top of the Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK version 3, which removed support for the Document class."